# How to take a string of data from a 2D array python (2.7)

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I'm sure this has been repeated since the dawn of time, but would anyone know how to access a string of data from a block as explained in better detail below:

```
array =

0,1,0,1,1,0

0,0,1,0,0,1

1,0,1,0,1,0

1,1,1,0,0,1
```

Want to access third row from element 2 to 6 to produce `0,1,0,0,1`

Want to access fourth row from element 6 to 2 to produce `1,0,0,1,1`

I have attempted to access data using this method:

```
Desired_info = Array(thrid_row, range(2, final_element)
Desired_info2 = Array(fourth_row, range(final_element, 2)
```

and my compiler crashes, I'm not sure if that's the right method but this is maddening and some assistance would be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
array=[[0,1,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0,0,1]]

array
```

[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

```
array[2][1:]
```

[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

```
array[3][:0:-1]
```

[1, 0, 0, 1, 1]